# Semi-circle diagram

Tags: android, kotlin, design-patterns

I want to create a semi-circle diagram something like this: [Semi-circle diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doArT.jpg).

But can't make it proper work dynamically. I want to use TextView, but can't make it exactly as it is in the photo.
This is what I've tried, but it's now wanted I want. And I don't have any solutions. Do you think you have some resources or code improvements for me?

```
val numViews = 8
        for (i in 0 until numViews) {
            // Create some quick TextViews that can be placed.
            val v = TextView(requireContext())
            // Set a text and center it in each view.
            v.text = "View $i"
            v.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
            v.setBackgroundColor(-0x10000)
            // Force the views to a nice size (150x100 px) that fits my display.
            // This should of course be done in a display size independent way.
            val lp = FrameLayout.LayoutParams(150, 250)
            // Place all views in the center of the layout. We'll transform them
            // away from there in the code below.
            lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
            // Set layout params on view.
            v.layoutParams = lp

            // Calculate the angle of the current view. Adjust by 90 degrees to
            // get View 0 at the top. We need the angle in degrees and radians.
            val angleDeg = i * 200.0f / numViews - 160.0f
            val angleRad = (angleDeg * Math.PI / 180.0f).toFloat()
            // Calculate the position of the view, offset from center (300 px from
            // center). Again, this should be done in a display size independent way.
            v.translationX = 300 * Math.cos(angleRad.toDouble()).toFloat()
            v.translationY = 300 * Math.sin(angleRad.toDouble()).toFloat()
            // Set the rotation of the view.
            v.rotation = angleDeg + 90.0f
            mBinding.main?.addView(v)
        }
```

Comment: Your link is broken FYI. Also it might help to say what your code's end result looks like, and why it's not what you want?

Comment: I don't think you're going to get anything like that with `TextView`s, especially if you want the text to curve with the circle like that (it's subtle but it's there). You'll at least have to make a custom view and draw the background wedges (using the methods on `Canvas`), then it's up to you if you try and align/rotate `TextView`s on top of that (which involves some complicated coordination) or if you just use `drawText` (or `drawTextOnPath` for the curve) on the Canvas. Personally I'd do the latter, it's easier to position and scale everything as part of one drawing process. Lots to learn!

Comment: Do you think you can help me with some code or some resources ?

Comment: If you're not familiar with custom views (especially working with paths) you need to learn that first - maybe this set of tutorials will help: https://blog.devgenius.io/working-with-lines-and-paths-custom-views-on-android-part-3-80aba21a82e1 (linking to part 3 so you can actually get to the previous parts). After that it's a bunch of maths like calculating the radius of your circle from the available view size, the width of each wedge where the text will be, the required text size to fit... I don't have time to develop that myself, sorry, there's a lot of work involved in this stuff